# Creating new GCP serverless vpc access connection, Error: Insufficient CPU quota in region

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I'm trying to create GCP serverless vpc access connection for my cloud functions.
The error message is at below
[image: error message]

So i checked quota of my project. and my quota is at below

[image: quota]

At first, I didn't have any VM instances so there was no cpu usage.
After, I create new VM instance, 8 quotas of CPUs are created. Still, it makes same error.

Do i need to use other type of cpu for VPC connection?
please share you knowledge. thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The error is quite specific and the root cause is the Quota of CPU. There are two possible reasons for this issue and two possible solutions.

First possible issue is the connectors being created using the gcloud command exceeded the CPU quota of your project. The second is there may be existing CPU resource hidden on your project that needs to be removed.

First solution is to change the [Gcloud command](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/configure-serverless-vpc-access#create-connector) you are using with lower `--max-instances` as additional parameter to lower the number of instance being created.

Example:

```
gcloud compute networks vpc-access connectors create my-connector \
  --region=REGION \
  --subnet-project=PROJECT \
  --subnet=SUBNET \
  --max-instances=3 \
  --min-instances=2
```

Second possible solution is QIR (Quota Increase Request), Requesting a quota increase is free of charge. It will only cost more if you uses more resource from your request. For detailed instructions on how to increase quota from the Google Cloud Console, see [Requesting a higher quota limit](https://cloud.google.com/docs/quota#requesting_higher_quota).

You can learn more about CPU Quota's [here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/quotas#cpu_quota).

Comment: Is this answer correct? If so mark accordingly to help others.