# GCP create connector - Insufficient CPU quota in region

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, gcloud, gcp-vpc-firewall

I am trying to create a serverless VPC connector as part of getting a static IP for Firebase functions in order to make egress calls through a static IP and followed these steps. https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/networking/network-settings#associate-static-ip

but I hit with this error.
[image]

Some of the answers from SO articles like below say need to increase the quota limit.

[Creating new GCP serverless vpc access connection, Error: Insufficient CPU quota in region](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70562667/creating-new-gcp-serverless-vpc-access-connection-error-insufficient-cpu-quota)
https://www.googlecloudcommunity.com/gc/Infrastructure-Compute-Storage/I-have-an-error-when-creating-a-VPC-Connector-with-this/m-p/550752#M3145

However, my question this is my first VPC network, connector, and subnet. So how come the quota is already crossed?

Note that my account is a billable account as some articles say the quota limit issue is due to 90-day free trial account.

Is there a solution without contacting GCP support?